# How can i print matrix[i][j] in python?

Tags: python

how can i print the matrix[i][j]?

```
from array import *

class Sudoku :

    matrix = []
    x = -1
    for i in range(0, 10):
        a = []
        for j in range(0, 10):
            try:
                a.append(int(input(f"Enter matrix{[i]}{[j]} element: ")))        
                if (isinstance(a, int)) == True :
                    matrix.append(a)
            except:
                matrix.append(x)        
              
    
    for i in range(0, 10):
        for j in range(0, 10):
            print(matrix[i][j])
```

error is :

```
print(matrix[i][j])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `matrix[i]` seems to be an `int` (presumably because you did `matrix.append(x)`, where `x` is an `int`. If you don't want the error, don't append `int`s into `matrix`.

Comment: The use of class seems odd.Seems your matix is like `[1,2,3...]` so matrix[0][0] means `1[0]` which is why it is throwing error

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code if you want to complete the code with minimum number of lines but it sure is a bit complex.

```
m,n=input("Enter num of rows and columns:").split()
                                                
matrix=[[int(input()) for y in range(int(n))]for x in range(int(m))]

[[[print(matrix[i][j], end=" ") for j in range(int(n))] and print(" ") ]for i in range(int(m))]
```

The output looks like this:

```
Enter num of rows and columns: 3 3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from array import *
class Sudoku:
    matrix = []
    x = -1  # <--- 4
    for i in range(0, 10):
        a = []
        for j in range(0, 10):
            try:
                a.append(int(input(f"Enter matrix{[i]}{[j]} element: ")))        
                if (isinstance(a, int)) == True :
                    matrix.append(a)  # <--- 11
            except:  # <--- 12
                matrix.append(x)  # <--- 13
    for i in range(0, 10):
        for j in range(0, 10):
            print(matrix[i][j])  # <--- 16
```

Let's look at the code. If `except` at L12 is catched, x, which is `-1` (L4) is appended. So at L16, when `matrix[i]` evaluates to `-1`, `-1[j]` is an error.
There's also another problem -- L11 will never be executed, because `a` is always a `list`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`matrix = []` is declaring matrix to be a list.  But you are thinking of the matrix as having i,j locations like in math.

You have two options:

Option1:  Map the list to a matrix

If you have a 3x3 matrix you have 9 locations, so
`matrix = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` is equivalent to

```
          0  1  2
matrix =  3  4  5
          6  7  8
```

so if wanted to print out this matrix you have to do some math to access the elements

```
for i in range(3):   # i = 0, 1, 2
   for j in range(3):  # j = 0, 1, 2
       print(matrix[3*i + j], end=" ")
   print("")
```

Option2:  Make matrix be a nested list

have matrix becomes a list of row, and each row is a list of elements

```
    matrix = []
    x = -1
    for i in range(0, 10):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, 10):
            while True:
                x = int(input(f"Enter matrix[{i}][{j}]} element: "))
                if (isinstance(x, int)) == True :
                    row.append(x)
                    break;
        matrix.append(row)     
   
    for i in range(0, 10):
        for j in range(0, 10):
            print(matrix[i][j])
```